# Elasticsearch: what my index contains: docs or positions?

Tags: elasticsearch, position

I've created ES index using the following command:

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"settings" :{"number_of_shards" : 10, "number_of_replicas" : 0, "analysis":{"analyzer": {"my_analyzer": {"type": "custom", "tokenizer":"whitespace","filter":["lowercase","porter_stem"],"stopwords":[...stopwords here ...]}}}}, "mappings" : {"html" : {"properties" : "head" : { "type" : "text", "analyzer": "my_analyzer" }, "body" : { "type" : "text", "analyzer": "my_analyzer"}}}}}' localhost:9200/docs
```

I read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-options.html) that:

> Analyzed string fields use positions as the default, and all other fields use docs as the default.

**Since my fields are of `text` type, are they considered string fields?**

My main issue is how to know what does my index contain (docs or positions?) for each field! I used `\docs\_settings` command to get the index settings, but didn't get useful answer?

Any hints?

### **EDIT**:

In addition answer of @ibexit below, I verified that practically by issuing phrase queries against ES indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the fields as text, without specifying index_options in your mapping. In this case the default for text fields will be applied (index_options=positions). The inverse index will now contain doc number, term frequencies, and term positions (or order) for the text fields.

For more in depth information about inverted indices please have a look on https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up or https://youtu.be/x37B_lCi_gc 
This should be a good starting point for your research.

Cheers!